# How to recognize/separate joint words using PHP?

Tags: php, dictionary, dns

I have tried asking this question before, but apparently provided too little detail and it was closed. Let me try again by being a bit more thorough:

What I need to do is separate any joint word, specifically in, say, domain names. If there is a domain "domainname.com", I need to have "domain" and "name" returned. If it's "stackoverflow.com", I need "stack" and "overflow" returned.

I imagine I need a word list to do this and that's not a problem. Keeping in mind that there are multiple ways some joint words may be separated ("stackoverflow.com" can be returned as "stack" and "overflow" or as "stack", "over" and "flow"), I've come up with this php function, but it needs improving.

```
 function make_words_capitalised( $str )
    {
// Full list of words
        $words = array( 'you', 'tube', 'my', 'space' );

// Capitalize separate words    
        foreach( $words as $word )
        {
            $str = str_ireplace( $word, ucfirst($word), $str );
        }

        return $str;
    }

var_dump( make_words_capitalised('youtube.com') );
var_dump( make_words_capitalised('myspace.com') );
```

Any and all ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: The first problem I can see with what your doing is what happens when you have a domain name that contains list words, i.e. `yoursitespace.com`. That would mess up using the above method. What I would suggest is having an array that contains the domain name as the key that points to an string. i.e. `array('youtube.com' => array('YOU TUBE'))`. Doing it this way would require a lot more config but would be a lot better that changing words

Comment: are words strictly alpha?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best I can do ( and I think it's pretty good )

```
function make_words_capitalised( $str, array $words)
{
    return str_ireplace($words, array_map('ucfirst', $words), $str);
}

var_dump( make_words_capitalised('youtube.com', ['you', 'tube']));
var_dump( make_words_capitalised('myspace.com', ['my', 'space']));
```

You can give an array to string replace, for the `search` and the `replace`. for the latter, we can use `array_map` and `ucfirst` to do the uppercase transform on them.

I also made the words list an argument, just seemed like the thing to do, because it will make it way more portable.

Outputs

```
string(11) "YouTube.com"
string(11) "MySpace.com"
```

You can test it here.

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d0b2367a5438701735f0c909c62f8289edaa08b4

This is essentially the same Idea you originally had, just cleaned up, and polished a bit.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, your approach is ok. I would just suggest using strtr() string PHP function about which you could read more in the official documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php).

Beside that, I would try to give a little more flexibility to this function and I would incapsulate it, together with all needed variables inside a class with static methods.

It would look something like this:

```
    class Capitalize
    {
  /**
   * @var array
   */
  private static $dictionary = ['you', 'tube', 'my', 'space'];
  /**
   * @var array
   */
  private static $transDictionary = [];

  /**
   * Capitalize all the words in the given text, based on the dictionary
   * @param $sentence
   * @return string
   */
  public static function capitalizeWords($sentence)
  {
    if (count(self::$transDictionary) == 0) {
      self::generateTransDictionary();
    }
    return strtr($sentence, self::$transDictionary);
  }


  /**
   * Generates a private translation dictionary based on the dictionary property
   */
  private static function generateTransDictionary()
  {
    $capWords = array_map('ucfirst', self::$dictionary);
    static::$transDictionary = array_combine(self::$dictionary, $capWords);
  }

  /**
   * Static getter - might be needed in the future
   * @return array
   */
  public static function getDictionary()
  {
    return self::$dictionary;
  }


  /**
   * @param $word
   */
  public static function addToDictionary($word)
  {
    static::$dictionary[] = $word;
    if (count (self::$transDictionary) != 0) self::generateTransDictionary();
  }
}


echo Capitalize::capitalizeWords('youtube.com');
echo Capitalize::capitalizeWords('spacetube.com');
Capitalize::addToDictionary('science');
echo Capitalize::capitalizeWords('sciencetube.com');
```

Comment: Nice job, you can just do this `array_map('ufirst', self::$dictionary)` no need for a closure.